# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_fetch_all()

Tags: php, mysqli

I get this error in my log, and my page doesn't load at all:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_fetch_all()
```

When I try on localhost everything is working fine, but when I upload to my shared hosting, I get this error. I've check in phpinfo and mysqlnd is enabled. Php version is 7.2.34.

This is the code I get my error on (mysqli_fetch_all in the middle):

```
$get_notification = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tbl_user_notification ORDER BY id DESC");
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_all($get_notification, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($get_notification);
```

Comment: RicoRico, yes, that helped. Actually, not the main answer but the one below, by javatar!